# How to use variables in jade file after it's rendered

Tags: node.js, express, pug

When I login, I'd like to be able to display the name of the user as a link in my index.jade file, but nothing shows up. I've tried both req.body.username, and req.session, and neither of them have worked. Here's the login controller:

```
const login = (req, res, next) => {
    var username = req.body.username
    var password = req.body.password

    User.findOne({$or: [{username:username}, {email:username}]})
    .then(user => {
        if(user) {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    res.json({
                        error: err
                    })
                }

                if(result) {
                    //Successful Login
                    let token = jwt.sign({name: user.name}, 'verySecretValue', {expiresIn: '1h'})
                    res.redirect('/')
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        message: 'Password does not match!'
                    })
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.json({
                message: 'No user found!'
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Here's my Routing to the homepage:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.query)
  res.render('index', { title: 'Portfolio', name:req.params.name });
}); 



module.exports = router;
```

And a snippet from my index.jade file where I want to insert the data:

```
extends layout

block content
  body
    // Topbar Start
    .container-fluid
      .row.bg-secondary.py-2.px-xl-5
        .col-lg-6.d-none.d-lg-block
          .d-inline-flex.align-items-center
            a.text-dark(href='') **#{req.body.username}**
            span.text-muted.px-2 |
            a.text-dark(href='') Help
            span.text-muted.px-2 |
            a.text-dark(href='') Support
```

Answer (score 1):

First, some comments on your code.

`req.params.name` is not in your route for `/`. The use of `req.params` is for managing a parameterized url, example if you have `router.get("/getprofile/:name");`, then a request url of `/getprofile/peter` will return "peter" in `req.params.name`.

`req.body` is present in a Http post request containing the Html control values inside the `<form>` in the submitted page. Anyway, you did not pass the `req` object to the view page in the render method, so it is not available in index.jade.

Solution:

What you need is to persist the user information across pages. Inside your login code, after the user is securely authenticated, you can use (signed) cookies or [session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) variables to set a `user` object to contain your user details:

```
if(result) {
    //Successful Login
    let token = jwt.sign({name: user.name}, 'verySecretValue', {expiresIn: '1h'})
    res.session.user = { name: user.name, email: "..." };
    res.redirect('/')
           }
```

Then you can pass to your view page with something like:

```
res.render("index", { user: req.session.user });
```

And in your view page:

```
a.text-dark(href='') #{user.namme}
```

Note: you have to first set up `express-session` as described in the above link.